# how to run a original database on my local server

Tags: mysql, server

I am totally a noob in server side development.
I have been given the task of using  a original `database` of a company and make a `copy on my local server` for testing the server.
I have the link and `username` and `password` too. 
What I don't know how to access the database given, I know the `username` and `password`.
I know `mysql` is used but I don't know which commands to use and how to use `mysql`. 
I tried googling it but couldn't find any solution.

I have sql workbench , how can I use it?

Comment: export all the tables, routines, etc. and import into your local server.It will be use full. If you have any sql browser like SQL workbench or Sql yog it will be easy for you .you can directly take back up through gui.Other wise you need to take sql dump back up.

Comment: can u tell me all the steps?

Comment: I've provided links to Import/Export guides in my answer. If you're as completely new to database work as you suggest, you are probably best off finding an introductory MySQL guide and starting from there, especially if you're going to be doing any work with the db.

Answer (score 0):

Export all the data from the Original DB and import it into the copy DB. A good export will include all the `Create Table` etc commands needed to replicate the DB in full.

Here are some examples of how to perform the Export and Import [using MySQLDump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/#more-184) and [using SQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html).